# Masters Qualification after PhD?

Tags: phd, masters, masters-post-phd

At the moment I am at the initial stages of my PhD, but there is a masters program (M.Sc) I love to follow after my PhD.

**Question 01**

> Is it possible to do a Masters Degree (M.Sc) after a PhD

**Question 02**

> If I follow a Masters Degree (M.SC) **after the PhD** is it considered as a **Post Doc** (Postdoctoral) qualification ?

---

*My Background*

*I have a B.Sc(Hons) first class, MBA, and M.Sc with 3.74 GPA*

Comment: 01) Of course. 02) Generally, no. Doing a Masters after a PhD is usually considered a step backward and not forward in your academic career.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to do that, but the qualification will in most cases not benefit you. In most cases the highest degree (in your case, your PhD) is all that people look at. So this is not done very often, because you have a cost (time, effort, tuition, lost pay) without benefit. If there is a limited number of places and the program needs to select its applicants, then this may be a reason to choose somebody else who will benefit more from that degree than you will.

However, most people continue to learn new things after a PhD. They just don't do it anymore as part of a degree offering program. This could be because of the costs I mentioned before. In some cases participating a MA program takes up resources that could be better spent on people who really need that degree, and it is the responsible thing not tie up those resources. Degree offering programs tend to be less flexible then learning things on your own. PhDs use a variety of strategies to learn new things: Sometimes you do it on your own. Sometimes through a MOOC. Sometimes some members of a department decide that they all want to learn a new topic together and meet weekly to discuss a given chapter. Sometimes, ...

As to the second question: definitely not. As I said before, the qualification is largely lost.

Comment: My late father-in-law got his PhD in physical chemistry in the 1950's. In the 1970's he decided to get a masters in geology, partly for fun and partly because he had started looking at the chemistry in some ore bodies and wanted to beef up his geology. The lab he worked at paid the tuition.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to question 1) I know a friend who did a PhD in Physics, after which she decided that she had enough with science, and did a masters in literature. It is not apparent in your question, but assuming that you want to do a masters in a completely unrelated field, and that it is your dream to do that masters, I will say go ahead! Sometimes, it is better late than never.

Answer to question 2) No, post-doc is not a degree.